# No type class instance was found, the instance head contains unknown type variables

Tags: purescript

Well, just simplified as possible:

There is a function that takes functor and does whatever

```
sToInt :: ∀ a s. Functor s => s a -> Int
sToInt val = unsafeCoerce val
```

Usage of this function with functor `S` which param (`v`) is functor too.

```
-- declare date type S that is functor
data S (v :: Type -> Type) a = S (v a)

instance functorS :: Functor v => Functor (S v) where
    map f (S a) = S (map f a)

sV :: ∀ v a. S v a
sV = unsafeCoerce 1

sss :: Int
sss = sToInt sV -- get the error here
```

```
No type class instance was found for

    Data.Functor.Functor t2

  The instance head contains unknown type variables. Consider adding a type annotation.

while applying a function sToInt
  of type Functor t0 => t0 t1 -> Int
  to argument sV
while checking that expression sToInt sV
  has type Int
in value declaration sss

where t0 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type
      t2 is an unknown type
```

So it doesn't like S Functor instance has `v` param Functor constraint, I wonder why getting this error and how to fix it for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have to do with `v` or with the specific shape of `S`. Try this instead:

```
sV :: forall f a. Functor f => f a
sV = unsafeCoerce 1

sss :: Int
sss = sToInt sV
```

You get a similar error.

Or here's an even more simplified version:

```
sV :: forall a. a
sV = unsafeCoerce 1

sss :: Int
sss = sToInt sV
```

Again, same error.

---

The problem is that `sToInt` must get a `Functor` instance as a parameter (that's what the `Functor s =>` bit in its type signature says), and in order to pick which `Functor` instance to pass, the compiler needs to know the type of the value. Like, if it's `Maybe a`, it will pass the `Functor Maybe` instance, and if it's `Array a`, it will pass the `Functor Array` instance, and so on.

Usually the type can be inferred from the context. For example when you say `map show [1,2,3]`, the compiler knows that `map` should come from `Functor Array`, because `[1,2,3] :: Array Int`.

But in your case there is nowhere to get that information: `sV` can return `S v` for any `v`, and `sToInt` can also take any functor type. There is nothing to tell the compiler what the type should be.

And the way to fix this is obvious: if there is no context information for the compiler to get the type from, you have to tell it what the type is yourself:

```
sss :: Int
sss = sToInt (sV :: S Maybe _)
```

This will be enough for the compiler to know that `v ~ Maybe`, and it will be able to construct a `Functor (S Maybe)` instance and pass it to `sToInt`.

---

Alternatively, if you want the consumer of `sss` to decide what `v` is, you can add an extra dummy parameter to capture the type, and require that the consumer pass in a `Functor v` instance:

```
sss :: forall v. Functor v => FProxy v -> Int
sss _ = sToInt (sV :: S v _)

ddd :: Int
ddd = sss (FProxy :: FProxy Maybe)
```

In Haskell you can do this with [visible type applications](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html) instead of `FProxy`, but PureScript, sadly, doesn't support that yet.

---

Even more alternatively, if `sToInt` doesn't actually care for a `Functor` instance, you can remove that constraint from it, and everything will work as-is:

```
sToInt :: forall s a. s a -> Int
sToInt a = unsafeCoerce a

sV :: forall v a. S v a
sV = unsafeCoerce 1

sss :: Int
sss = sToInt sV
```

This works because PureScript allows for ambiguous (aka "unknown") types to exist as long as they're not used for selecting instances.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. sToInt cares about s is Functor. When I say about Functor v, I mean there `instance functorS :: Functor v => ...` if to remove constraint (need to change the implementation of instance) then there would be no error. So adding type `(sV :: S v _)` would work (though for my real case seems something else would be needed). I wonder why adding type anotation to `sV :: ∀ v a. Functor v => S v a` does not work?

Comment: marking as correct as it helped me to resolve with explicitly annotating the params inside the function. I just really wonder why PS requires `(sV :: S v _)` explicit annotation if `sV` is explicitly typed in the scope, but this some basic concept that I just didn't grasp yet.

Comment: Even if you have a `v` in scope when referencing `sV` (which you didn't mention in your question, btw), it's not enough, because it might be a different `v`. For all the compiler knows, the two `v`s just happen to have the same name.

Comment: I mean `sV` is in the scope and annotated as `sV :: ∀ v a. Functor v => S v a`, what prevents it from being taken for granted (inside `sss`)? I guess that PS type system probably isn't supposed to work this way, but I wonder the motivation.

Comment: It is taken for granted. The `Functor v =>` part of the type signature says that you have to pass a `Functor` instance as a parameter, and in order to pick such instance, the compiler needs to know what `v` is.